# code review tool

Tags: android

Which open source code review tool can i use for my android apps.

Comment: Can you make the question more specific?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using eclipse you can try [Jupiter](http://code.google.com/p/jupiter-eclipse-plugin/) or the [Collaborative Code Review Tool](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/collaborative-code-review-tool). There's also a web-based one called [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) for projects using Git. I don't know much about it, but a lot of people seem to like it.

Comment: hmm, after reading the other comment, I'm not even sure if this is what you're looking for :) These are for collaborative code reviews among teams. The others are for automatically reviewing code to determine probable bugs.

Comment: Another in this family is Rietveld.  See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rietveld.html for more.

Answer (score 0):

We have also invented a review tool. But it is a plugin for the IDE Eclpise. I hope this is no problem for you.
If you want some more information, look here: [Agilereview](http://agilereview.sf.net)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

Also, search in java category in general: [Best free Code Review tool for Eclipse/Java/Flex Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878506/best-free-code-review-tool-for-eclipse-java-flex-development).